# How to write cucumber test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone tell me how to write cucumber testcases as am new to this.Suggest me best tutorial togo through for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) is nice

Nice book for basic setup: [The Cucumber Book: Behaviour-Driven Development for Developers and Testers](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book)

Also, the Nettuts+ tutorial: [Ruby for Newbies: Testing Web Apps with Capybara and Cucumber](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-testing-web-apps-with-capybara-and-cucumber/)

Answer (score 2):

This [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) is the best out there.  Do checkout part 2 as well!  BTW, in cucumber parlance, they are called 'features' where you describe scenarios.

I can personally recommend "*The RSpec Book: Behaviour-Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends*" if you want to know more about BDD with Cucumber although I am in no way related to the authour(s) and/or the publisher.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have setup cucumber, I would recommend to use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines